# AMPScript: How can use DecryptSymmetric() function to decrypt an encrypted string from PHP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to decrypt an encrypted string using AMPScript's DecryptSymmetric() function which is coming from an external system(PHP).

I am not sure which algorithm PHP should use to encrypt the string, so that I can decrypt that string using AMPScript's DecryptSymmetric() function.

Answer (score 0):

I had achieved something similar with C# and the DES algorithm quite some time ago, you might be able to get some points for AES.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31409/5340

Comment: I could encrypt and decrypt the data using DES in PHP & SFMC respectively. But I wanted to know if it can be done for AES. I tried in C#, it works with DES, but it is not working with AES.